How to draw a single Spark monotonically increasing id and pass it to Dataset.map()
Using Java Spark to transform a dataset of object A into a dataset of object B, I use
Encoder<B> encoder = Encoders.bean(B.class);
Dataset<B> datasetB = datasetA.map(x -> service.generate(x), encoder) 
// where service interface has a function such as "B generate(A a)"

My idea is to separate the business logic in a package which is spark-agnostic and all the big data code with Spark in another package (calling the business logic package).
That idea worked fairly well for me so far (with the caveat of making a bunch of class implement serializable interface in business logic) but starts to struggle when I want to generate unique identifier for my business objects. I need some kind of synchronization to avoid duplicate Ids and the business logic package should not know it is actually ran on several worker nodes.
I thought about using something based on epoch but testing with 10M id generations showed a few hundreds id conflict when using System.nanotime() as id, even on a single node.
Is it possible to draw a monotonically_increasing_id() with Spark and pass it to the Dataset.map() call ? Is the only solution to add or fill my id column after the map transformation ?
Edit : I just got this idea
 Dataset<A> a = b.rdd().zipWithIndex().map(x -> service.generate(x._1(), x._2()), ablEncoder);

But x is a scala.Tuple2<a, Object> but I can't seem to be able to access its elements despite them being public ?
Edit2 : Tuple2 is usable if I use toJavaRDD() instead of rdd()
Does it seems the correct way ?

Maybe you can add a prefix/suffix based on the node so the majority of the id is still sortable across nodes (unless it doesn't have to be) - only elements using the exact same timestamp would be ordered somewhat arbitrarily which means by node.

Timestamp provided by JVM aren't accurate enough, I get 300ish duplicate node when I try to generate 10M id in a unit test. I edited my post with an idea I had but I struggle reaching properties of objects provided by the scala package.

If you can base the ids that are generated off unique data in the elements you're converting then I'd favor that approach. If you can't - then adding a timestamp might help but there's still a chance of that not being unique. So maybe you can provide some counter as well, e.g. reset the counter whenever you get a new timestamp on a node and increase it when you don't. The resulting id might then have a form like [timestamp]-[counter]-[node].

This problem is not so straightforward to solve, for Quality we added a snowflake id like guaranteed unique row id dependent on mac address uniqueness only, combined with partition id, starting timestamp and a counter (160bit, an integer and two longs).
A key drawback of this approach is re-running an action using the function multiple times generates new unique id's, so writing the results out first then using them is the only way to guarantee typically expected behaviour.
monotonocally_incrementing_id only provides a counter per partition and is only unique within a dataframe, so repeated runs of your process will end up with collisions.
